# NUnit GUI Runner for Windows Phone 8 class library - problems with some System libraries

Tags: windows-phone-8, nunit, visual-studio-express

I'm working on library projects for Windows Phone 8, and using NUnit for unit-testing. My IDE is Visual Studio 2012 Express edition for WP8. It'd been so far so good until a day when it happened to some tests failing saying that it's unable to load some system packages (in particular, System.Xml and System.Net version 2.0.5.0). So I tried:

1. Looked for the System.Xml and System.Net version 2.0.5.0 so that I could GAC them somehow , but found them nowhere. The closest version I have is 2.0.50272. I indeed tried to use this, it didn't complain anymore but the XmlSerializer.CreateReader and CreateWriter returned null... So the tests failed eventually after that.
2. Checked out the NUnit and upgraded the projects there to base on .NET 4.0, re-deployed to used this newly built NUnit framework and runner... It didn't work, the same error occurred.

When debugging, I saw it looked like the NUnit GUI loads the dependencies of my libraries using .NET framework run-time 2.0. Although all my libraries are Windows Phone 8 based. Would be very appreciative if someone could shed me some light on this.